# Как поставить значение верный "http_version" запроса от навыка Алисы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, яндекс-алиса

Запустил навык на FastApi на своей машине. Прокинул через **ngrok** свой адрес и указал в Настройках навыка.

Но при отправке запроса, значение http_version = 1.0
А я на своей машине через:

```
request.get('http_version')
```

получаю значение http_version = 1.1? Которое и отправляю

Соответственно, выходит ошибка:

> 1. Недопустимое значение поля: version

Если указать вручную значение в отправке http_version = 1.0, то ошибки никакой нет.

Хотелось бы узнать как получить верное значение?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728124/how-to-define-the-http-protocol-version-in-requests

Comment: @zxcqwe, Вы хоть сами прочитали свою ссылку? Там написано как установить. А зачем мне знать как устанавливать, если я знаю как менять значение версии.
Меня интересует почему оно меняется?

Comment: потому что  из документации requests *Requests allows you to send HTTP/1.1 requests*